# Recursive function to flatten complex XML structure in R

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I've had a number of projects requiring XML processing in R and I've always struggled. The problem is always the same: parsing someone else's complex XML structure into a workable dataframe.

Example below of my usual problem. With the data I work with, node names are not necessarily consistent between files, I usually just want to flatten with each dataframe row at the level of the deepest level and then fill columns with adult node names or attributes.

Want to get from this:

```
library(XML)
# Small example extract
# Most data points removed

xml_extract <- xmlParse("
<COMPARISON ID=\"CMP-001\" NO=\"1\">
    <NAME>Incomplete resection (HGG)</NAME>
    <DICH_SUBGROUP CHI2=\"0.0\" CI_END=\"0.0\" CI_START=\"0.0\">
        <NAME>iMRI</NAME>
        <DICH_DATA CI_END=\"0.9640231041199472\" CI_START=\"0.017586933339032232\"/>
    </DICH_SUBGROUP>
    <DICH_SUBGROUP CHI2=\"0.0\" CI_END=\"0.0\" CI_START=\"0.0\">
        <NAME>5-ALA</NAME>
        <DICH_DATA CI_END=\"0.7124078544369572\" CI_START=\"0.4242461206130219\"/>
    </DICH_SUBGROUP>
    <DICH_SUBGROUP CHI2=\"0.0\" CI_END=\"0.0\" CI_START=\"0.0\">
        <NAME>DTI-neuronavigation</NAME>
        <DICH_DATA CI_END=\"0.6302184844574396\" CI_START=\"0.19776580326143214\"/>
    </DICH_SUBGROUP>
</COMPARISON>
")
```

To this:

[image: dataframe]

(I know two of these columns have the same `NAME`, part of the problem. Not my XML).

I use `XML` and have had a look at `XML2R`. I'm familiar-ish with `XPath`. Standard `xmlToDataFrame` type commands don't work. Standard `Apply` approaches such as `xmlSApply`or `plyr` for lists usually require completely standardised node names.

Is what I'm looking for possible? A recursive function that run through and flatten an XML stucture. I know I have conveniently omitted the bits I don't want from the XML extract in the table :) Thank you in advance!

---

Edit to provide more complex and typical example.

Thank you very much for your help with this, particularly hrbmstr. Your solution has been my approach in the past. I have 8000 documents with significant variations on the example, hence was looking for a solution where variable names were defined by XML content, rather than by the function.

Complex but typical example here:

```
library(httr)
library(XML)
url = "http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD007635.pub2/downloadstats"
response = POST(url, body = list("tAndCs" = TRUE))

xml_record = content(response, "parsed", type="text/xml")
path = "//ANALYSES_AND_DATA"
xml_extract = xml_record[[path]]
```

There is an [R interface for XSLT](http://www.omegahat.org/Sxslt/) which I have no experience with. Nor XSLT.

Comment: Tasks like this always seem to me like a good fit for XSLT solutions. I'm surprised there doesn't appears to be a package with good XSLT support for R.

Comment: @MrFlick Now there is https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xslt/index.html . Haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

It just requires "attacking" the XML systematically (no XSLT required):

```
data.frame(comparison=xpathSApply(xml_extract, "//COMPARISON", xmlGetAttr, "ID"),
           name=xpathSApply(xml_extract, "//COMPARISON/NAME", xmlValue),
           dich_name=xpathSApply(xml_extract, "//COMPARISON/DICH_SUBGROUP/NAME", xmlValue),
           ci_end=xpathSApply(xml_extract, "//COMPARISON/DICH_SUBGROUP/DICH_DATA", xmlGetAttr, "CI_END"),
           ci_end=xpathSApply(xml_extract, "//COMPARISON/DICH_SUBGROUP/DICH_DATA", xmlGetAttr, "CI_START")
)

##   comparison                       name           dich_name             ci_end             ci_end.1
## 1    CMP-001 Incomplete resection (HGG)                iMRI 0.9640231041199472 0.017586933339032232
## 2    CMP-001 Incomplete resection (HGG)               5-ALA 0.7124078544369572   0.4242461206130219
## 3    CMP-001 Incomplete resection (HGG) DTI-neuronavigation 0.6302184844574396  0.19776580326143214
```

Please post a more complex XML sample if this doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: When in doubt, apply brute force.  Nice

Comment: A generalized example would be even more ugly (which I'm hoping the OP doesn't need :-)

Comment: I gave this a go earlier.  Bummer you can't see my deleted answer though.  I got some of the info with just `lapply(xmlRoot(doc)[-1], function(x)  c(NAME = xmlValue(x), xmlAttrs(x[[2]])))`